# SQLite returned rows count is zero

Tags: java, android, sqlite

```
   public class SQLiteProvider extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static SQLiteDatabase sqliteDatabase ;  

    public SQLiteProvider ( Context context ) {
        super ( context , DATABASE_NAME , null , DATABASE_VERSION ) ;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate ( SQLiteDatabase sqliteDatabase ) {
        try {
            this . sqliteDatabase = this . getWriteabaleDataBase ( ) ;
            this . sqliteDatabase . execSQL ( TABLE_CREATE ) ;
            this . sqliteDatabase . close ( ) ;
        } catch ( Exception exception ) {
            Log . i ( LOG_TAG , "Exception is `" + exception . toString ( ) + "`" ) ;
        }
    }

    private void insert ( String column1Value , String column2Value ) {
        try {
            sqliteDatabase = this . getWritableDatabase ( ) ;
            sqliteDatabase . execSQL ( QUERY_TO_INSERT ) ;
            sqliteDatabase . close ( ) ;
        } catch ( Exception exception ) {
            Log . i ( LOG_TAG , "Exception is `" + exception . toString ( ) + "`" ) ;
        }
    }

    private String selectColumn1byColumn2 ( String column2Value ) {
        try {
            sqliteDatabase . getWritableDatabase ( ) ;
            cursor = sqliteDatabase . rawQuery ( SELECT_QUERY ) ;
            sqliteDatabase . close ( )
        } catch ( Exception exception ) {
            Log . i ( LOG_TAG , "Exception is `" + exception . toString ( ) + "`" ) ;
        }
        if ( cursor . getCount ( ) > 0 ) {
            return cursor . getString ( 0 ) ;
        } else { 
            Log . i ( LOG_TAG , "selectColumn1byColumn2 row count is zero " ) ; 
            return "";
        }
    }

    public String doIt ( ) {
        insert ( VARIABLE1 , VARIABLE2 ) ;
        return selectColumn1byColumn2 ( VARIABLE2 ) ;
    }
}
```

All methods use same sqliteDatabase object and each of it calls getWritableDatabase in the beginning.
Function doIt ( ) return just empty string and Log that row count is zero ( `selectColumn1byColumn2 row count is zero` ) and no one exception. I do it with transaction and without , both of it does not work
How do I it right?

update April 8

I have done

Add finally block with `sqliteDatabase . close ( )`

Add `cursor . close ( )` when it necessary before `sqliteDatabase . close ( )`

Change `cursor . getString ( 0 )` to `cursor . getString ( cursor . getColumnIndex ( TABLE_COLUMN1 ) )`

Change `if ( cursor . getCount ( ) > 0 )` to `if ( cursor . moveToFirst ( ) )`

And now it returns row count is zero and don`t work on Jelly Bean 4.2 - android application crashes

Answer (score 1):

Change your selectColumn1byColumn2() method as folllows

```
 private String selectColumn1byColumn2 ( String column2Value ) {
        try {
            sqliteDatabase . getWritableDatabase ( ) ;
            cursor = sqliteDatabase . rawQuery ( SELECT_QUERY ) ;
             if ( cursor . getCount ( ) > 0 ) {
            return cursor . getString ( 0 ) ;
        } else { 
            Log . i ( LOG_TAG , "selectColumn1byColumn2 row count is zero " ) ; 
            return "";
          }
```

> <strike>sqliteDatabase . close ( );</strike>

```
        } catch ( Exception exception ) {
            Log . i ( LOG_TAG , "Exception is `" + exception . toString ( ) + "`" ) ;
        }
         finally
        {
          cursor.close();
          sqliteDatabase . close ( );
        }
```

Comment: But I have another error after that android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException Index -1 requested with a size of 32

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you are not getting the desired result is because you are closing the database first and then reading from the cursor.

If you first read from the cursur, and when you are finished using the cursor close your database, it should work.

The user named alibi gives a good explanation in his answer: [Clicky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450050/android-sqlitedatabases-and-cursors)

> 1) The cursor is just a pointer to the data returned by your query, it doesn't contain all the data from your query. This is to increase performance/efficiency (large resultsets aren't read at once -> less memory used). Therefore, if you close the database, the cursor can't retrieve the data -> it's empty.
>
> 2) When you close a cursor, all associated resources are released ->
>   you can't access the data associated with this cursor (since it has
>   been released), but you can make new queries using this or other
>   cursors. When you close a database, you can't query it anymore (until
>   you re-open it).
>
> 3) Always close cursors. Otherwise you will run into problems - the GC
>   will complain if the cursor isn't closed and new queries are blocked.
>
> 4) If you close it when your app finishes, yes

again, credit goes to alibi.

#### UPDATE

```
private String selectColumn1byColumn2 ( String column2Value ) {
    try {
        sqliteDatabase . getWritableDatabase ( ) ;
        cursor = sqliteDatabase . rawQuery ( SELECT_QUERY ) ;

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if ( cursor . getCount ( ) > 0 ) {
            return cursor . getString ( 0 ) ;
        } else { 
            Log . i ( LOG_TAG , "selectColumn1byColumn2 row count is zero " ) ; 
            return "";
        }
    } catch ( Exception exception ) {
        Log . i ( LOG_TAG , "Exception is `" + exception . toString ( ) + "`" ) ;
    } finally {
        cursor.close(); 
        sqliteDatabase . close ( );
    }
}
```

cursor.close and sqliteDatabase.close() are moved to a finally block. This will ensure the database and cursor gets cleaned up properly when you are done using it.

Also I added a cursor.moveToFirst(); call before your first call to getCount();

Not 100% sure it's needed but it's worth a try.

Comment: @Sunshine I updated my post. I'm not 100% sure but I believe if you are still getting errors with the cursor.close() and sqliteDatabase.close() in place, the problem might be that you need a call to cursor.moveToFirst(); I believe this initializes the actual data rather then just meta data(such as column names)

Comment: `cursor . moveToFirst ( ) ;

if ( cursor . getCount ( ) > 0 {`

it equals
`if ( cursor . moveToFirst ( ) ) {`

Isn't? I do it like this and `cursor . close ( ) ;` in finally-block, and it wrote that row count is zero and throws no one exception

Comment: @Sunshine deleted comment to place a new one. As far as the android docs concern, the documentation sais nothing about getCount() doing a call to moveToFirst(). It would not make sense because what if you are looping trough a cursor and in the body of the loop you need cursor.getCount() for some calculations? It would create an infinite loop. Which is easily fixable, but you get the point. Honestly I don't know wether getCount does or does not call moveToFirst().